# ! Missing delimiter (. inserted). <to be read again> error

Tags: equations, errors, delimiters

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl} %\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  |u|_{p(x)}=\inf\left \{\tau>0;\int_{\Omega}\left|\frac{u}{\tau}\right|^{p(x)}\,dx\leq 1\right\}.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

I can't figure out why this code won't work. Thanks

```
! Missing delimiter (. inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.6 ...(x)}=\inf\left \{\tau>0;\int_{\Omega}\left|
                                                  \frac{u}{\tau}\right|^{p(x...

?
```

Comment: please always provide a complete small document not just a fragment, in particular `equation*` is not defined by default, so we have to guess which packages to load

Comment: Assuming a package or class, I'm not getting an error.

Comment: If I define `equation*` by loading `amsmath` then your fragment gives no error.

Comment: I wrapped your fragment in `\documentclass...\end{document}` please further edit so that the code produces the error shown.

Answer (score 1):

The posted code produces no error, and you have only shown a fragment of the error message. If I edit your example to produce the error, so the input is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  |u|_{p(x)}=\inf\left x\{\tau>0;\int_{\Omega}\left|\frac{u}{\tau}\right|^{p(x)}\,dx\leq 1\right\}.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The the error message is

```
! Missing delimiter (. inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   x
l.6   |u|_{p(x)}=\inf\left x
                            \{\tau>0;\int_{\Omega}\left|\frac{u}{\tau}\right...

?
```

The error message is then as you showed, but the important part is the context display that you did not show.

The `l.6` tells you it is on line 6 and the linebreak in the display shows you the point that TeX had reached, so here it had stopped after an `x` following `\left` and has not yet scanned the rest of the equation (which is shown after the linebreak).

In general the error is generated by a non-delimiter following `\left` or `\right` and the full error message will show the offending character (`x` here) as the last character before the line break in the error context display.

---

Here using the class mentioned in comments the error message is

```
! Missing delimiter (. inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.6 ...(x)}=\inf\left \{\tau>0;\int_{\Omega}\left|
                                                  \frac{u}{\tau}\right|^{p(x...

?
```

showing that in this class `|` has a non standard definition which is not a delimiter. You can use the command forms `\lvert` and `\rvert` to obtain the original characer:

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl} %\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\show|
\begin{equation*}
  |u|_{p(x)}=\inf\left \{\tau>0;\int_{\Omega}\left\lvert\frac{u}{\tau}\right\vert^{p(x)}\,dx\leq 1\right\}.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

alternatively `program` package (the real culprit here) provides `\normalbaroutside` to avoid breaking standard markup. so

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl} %\documentclass{article}
\normalbaroutside
\begin{document}


\begin{equation*}
  |u|_{p(x)}=\inf\left \{\tau>0;\int_{\Omega}\left|\frac{u}{\tau}\right|^{p(x)}\,dx\leq 1\right\}.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for  your quik responses.

Comment: Thank you for  your quik responses.  Yes it is about context, in fact i  usee this forumla with the Springer Nature template.  \documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl} ,  Math and Physical Sciences Reference Style .

Comment: @user263802 if you showed the error message as I did, somone could help, prefereably also show your input. But if you do not show any input that generates the error and do not show the error message it is hard to give any more help than the general advice I give here.

Comment: @user263802 actually I have that class, I will update your question and my answer, give me a couple of minutes

Comment: @user263802 answer updated

Comment: @user263802 the actual culprit is the ``program` package that is loaded by the class (this package has come up before and makes several unfortunately global changes rather than restricting the chnages to its own environment)

Comment: Thank you, you saved my life

Comment: @user263802 ok glad you got it working, next time please provide a test file, the question would never have got the answer you wanted without reference to the class, which wasn't in the question (unil I added based on your commnt here) It's a feature of tex as a language that it is highly context dependent and a fragment almost always is not enough to debug it needs a full document.